# NIntegral failing to converge

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, warning-messages

I have the following integrals that I am trying to calculate:

```
a[q_, E_, K_, y_] = 1 + q/(2*K)*Log[(q^2 - K*q - E)/(q^2 + K*q - E)];

f[Epol_?NumericQ, K_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[a[q, Epol, K, y],{q, y, Infinity}, Method -> "GlobalAdaptive", WorkingPrecision -> 20, MaxPoints -> 100];

rhs[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, Epol_?NumericQ] := 4/Pi *NIntegrate[K^2/(x - 2/Pi *y + K^2/4 + Epol - 2/Pi*f[Epol, K, y]), {K, 0,y},Method -> "GlobalAdaptive", MaxPoints -> 100];
```

Then I want to use that to solve an equation as the following:

```
FindRoot[E == rhs[0.2, 1, E], {E, -0.01}]
```

I'm getting always the convergence error in the integral:

> NIntegrate::maxp: The integral failed to converge after 121 integrand evaluations. NIntegrate obtained 0.0818604 +0.0435709 I and 0.0005506179310998352` for the integral and error estimates.

I tried to change the maximum number of evaluation points allowed, the working precision, and the accuracy/precision goals, nothing has worked out well for values of x more than 0.1, any other solutions to try are welcome.

Comment: Even the `f` function really struggles to return a value when I plug in some random input. Are you confident that these integrals are convergent? Can you provide a set of values for the parameters for which `f` returns without errors or warnings?

Comment: `FindRoot[E == rhs[-0.5, 0.1, E], {E, -0.01}]` for example

Comment: [Avoid using capital letters for variables](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/4999), especially ones used by *Mathematica* for other purposes, such as `E` (base of the natural logarithm) and `K` (dummy summation/integration variable).

Answer (score 1):

Multiple problems with your code. Here is better code:

```
Clear[a, f, rhs]

a[q_, E_, K_, y_] := 1 + q/(2*K)*Log[(q^2 - K*q - E)/(q^2 + K*q - E)];

f[Epol_?NumericQ, K_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[a[q, Epol, K, y], {q, y, Infinity}, 
   Method -> "GlobalAdaptive", WorkingPrecision -> 20, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 2];

rhs[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, Epol_?NumericQ] := 
  4/Pi*NIntegrate[
    K^2/(x - 2/Pi*y + K^2/4 + Epol - 2/Pi*f[Epol, K, y]), {K, 0, y}, 
    Method -> "GlobalAdaptive", PrecisionGoal -> 2];

FindRoot[var == rhs[0.2, 1, var], {var, -0.01}] 

(* Lots of messages.. *)
(* {var -> -0.010069} *)
```

> [...] nothing has worked out well for values of x more than 0.1 [...]

Is this something you expect:

```
FindRoot[var == rhs[12, 1, var], {var, -0.01}]

(* {var -> 0.036143} *)
```

Comment: I don't clearly see what changes have you made except for reducing the precision goal, which I have already tried. I think I have figured out the problem, it has to do with how Mathematica searches for solutions in `FindRoot`. A possible workaround is to put a starting point very close to the result to be able to avoid these convergence problems. For instance `FindRoot[var == rhs[0.2, 1, var], {var, -0.44}] `gives a value which is logical (based on what I know of the behavior of this equation) without any error messages.

Comment: But this is not a trustworthy solution since it means the equation has a solution around this value which leads to a convergent integral. Also, I might not have always an intuition of the logical outcome, which means predicting the starting point becomes harder. Anyway, I will try to write a code in python since I'm better at debugging there, I don't think I will get it to work with mathematica.

Comment: @RagheedAlhyder "I don't clearly see what changes have you made except for reducing the precision goal [...] " -- look more carefully.

Comment: Sorry I don't see it, is it the removal of maximum points? Anyway the performance has stayed the same.

Answer (score 1):

Do as much of integration you can analytically.

```
a[q_, EE_, K_, y_] = 
  1 + q/(2*K)*Log[(q^2 - K*q - EE)/(q^2 + K*q - EE)] // 
FullSimplify[#, 0 < K < y < 1 && q > y && Element[{EE}, Reals]] &

int = Integrate[a[q, EE, K, y], {q, y, \[Infinity]}, 
        Assumptions -> 0 < K < y < 1 && q > y && Element[{EE}, Reals]]

{*   ConditionalExpression[(1/(
   4 K))(K Sqrt[-4 EE - K^2] \[Pi] + 
  K Sqrt[-4 EE - 
 K^2] (ArcTan[(K - 2 y)/Sqrt[-4 EE - K^2]] - 
  ArcTan[(K + 2 y)/Sqrt[-4 EE - K^2]]) + (2 EE + K^2) ArcTanh[(
 K y)/(EE - y^2)] - 
 y (2 K + y Log[1 + (2 K y)/(EE - y (K + y))])), 4 EE + K^2 < 0] 
     *}
```

.

```
ff[EE_, K_, y_] = int[[1]];

rhs[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, Epol_?NumericQ] := 
   4/Pi*NIntegrate[
   K^2/(x - 2/Pi*y + K^2/4 + Epol - 2/Pi*ff[Epol, K, y]), {K, 0, y}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 50]

EEfr[x_, y_] := EE /. First@FindRoot[EE == rhs[x, y, EE], {EE, -.1}]
```

Here a plot of Epol for negative x. for positive x there are more convergence problems may be due to low working precision. Further the condition with analytical integral `4 EE + K^2 < 0` has to be regarded.

```
pl = Plot3D[EEfr[x, y], {x, -5, 0}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 10]
```

[image]